# Weird behavior when execute and echo are used together

Tags: echo, execute

So I was doing some testing on some function I made, let's call it `Test_mode`,

```
"let g:Test_mode = 0 " commented to show that it works without defining it first
function! Test_mode()
if g:Test_mode == "off"
  nnoremap <buffer> <Down> <Down>
  nnoremap <buffer> <Up> <Up>
elseif g:Test_mode == "on"
  noremap <buffer><expr> <Down> Another_function()
  noremap <buffer><expr> <Up> Yet_another_function()
endif
endfunction

function! Togglemode(argument)
  redir >> event.log
  echo execute(a:argument)
" where the weird behavior occur
  redir END
endfun

noremap <buffer> <expr> c Togglemode("g:Test_mode")
```

Again, the above was just me playing around with some vimscript features.

Anyway, it seems to me like the `execute` + `echo` combination above make it so that the output is actually the `Test_mode` variable location (where/line where it's defined) and the content of the function of the same name...

I don't get why `execute` would do this since my initial attempt was to see if I could turn off/on a variable by passing it as an argument, but that resulted in seeing the function's content echoed on the screen + the variable using the same name.

By the way, this only happen if I use `g:Test_mode`, so if I do it without passing `g:` in front, it won't work. And yes, as mentioned in the commented code, it works the same even if I comment the part of the code where the variable is defined...

Is this normal behavior? a bug? I'm just curious if this is really a weird behavior.

P.S: I don't think I was clear enough when I said "it output the content of the function", so I'd like to clarify this point.

Basically, if I use the keybinding set above, which is `c` in normal mode, I get this as output:

```
"let g:Test_mode = 0 " commented to show that it works without defining it first
function! Test_mode()
if g:Test_mode == "off"
elseif g:Test_mode == "on"
noremap <buffer> <expr> c Togglemode("g:Test_mode")
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Which is *literally* the code of the function above. *That's* the weird behavior I mentioned above.

It would make sense if I had this as output if I was trying to capture whatever `execute` is executing, but that doesn't look like that to me. It kind of look like more of a `string matching` of the global variable I passed to `execute`.

Comment: I think you're mixing some stuff here. `Togglemode("g:Test_mode")`: you are calling your function with the string `"g:Test_mode"` which has nothing to do with the variable if you want to pass the variable as parameter remove the quotes. `execute(a:argument)`: since the argument is a variable holding a boolean it doesn't make sense to execute it, what would make sense would be to have a string representing an actual command to execute.

Comment: Also you are using the same name for a variable and a function: First read [`:h variable-scope`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#variable-scope) and remember that in most programming language it's usually a bad idea to use non unique names. I know these comments don't really answer your questions (and I'm sure someone else will) but still I think they are good advice to keep in mind.

Comment: ah, I never said any of what I shown here was good practices/good idea, since, I did said this was just me `playing around` or testing things :) also, please try the code I posted with the keybinding and you'll see what I meant by "it output the content of the function"...@statox

Comment: also, I'm aware I should have tried to put it without quotes, but beside the fact it's beside the point of this question, I did mention I notice this weird behavior *when* I tried to toggle some global variable, so, if I try and pass it to the Togglemode function, it will only return the content of the variable, not the variable's name as string, which is what I tried to do (although that's as I mentioned, beside the point of this question) @statox

Comment: feel free to check the question again -- I think I clarified what I meant better :D @statox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seemingly odd behavior you're seeing is because the `execute()` function actually runs its argument as an Ex command.

So when you pass it `"g:Test_mode"`, it's actually running the [`:g`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Ag) or `:global` command, using `:` as a separator, then the `Test_mode` regex and finally an implicit [`:p`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Ap) to print the lines matching the regex (which is the default command if `:g` doesn't get a command explicitly.)

So the output you're seeing is that of:

```
:g/Test_mode/p
```

Which you can also get with:

```
:g:Test_mode
```

The `execute()` function is capturing that output as a string, then passing it to `echo`, so you end up seeing it that way. You'd get the same result if you used:

```
:echo execute('g/Test_mode/p')
```

If you want to pass the function a string containing the name of a variable and then get the contents of that variable, you can use [`eval()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#eval%28%29) instead. For example, for the contents of `g:Test_mode`:

```
:echo eval("g:Test_mode")
```

If you're specifically interested in a global variable and have its name passed as a string, you can also use [`get()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#get%28%29) in the `g:` namespace:

```
:echo get(g:, 'Test_mode')
```

In that case, you can also pass `get()` a third argument to use in case `g:Test_mode` is not actually defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought this was too odd of an issue to be answered/known :) I wonder, is this even documented in some way?

Comment: nevermind, it's documented (looked into the inline links on your answer). Cheers